# How to read timer countdown with high accuracy from Tekken 7 using opencv, tesseract?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

[THRESH_BINARY sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkPQU.png)

[THRESH_BINARY_INV sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6Sh.png)
I'm trying to read data from each frame of Tekken 7 game, and my first step is to take digits from timer by using tesseract. Before calling tesseract I apply gray mask and threshold:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 70, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
_, thresh_text = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 4)
```

I've tried THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV to take last image before calling tesseract.

Calling tesseract:

```
timer = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        timer_img,
        lang='eng',
        nice=1,
        config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789 --psm 7'
      )
```

I've also tried psm 6, but nothing changed. Result of OCR is empty result, sometimes on 57,47,37,27 seconds tesseract recognises digit 7, but not both digits.

I'm using:
python 3.8,
tesseract 5,
opencv-python==4.4.0.46
pytesseract==0.3.10

I've tried different thresholds on opencv and psm on tesseract, but no digits or not all digits were recognised.

Expected befaviour: all digits are returned.